# Selecting 1 column's value in a group after grouping by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would I include the name of any **one** of the books that belong to that particular type in the below query?

```sql
select distinct
(select sum(ob.Balance)),
ob.BookType
from orders.OrderBooks ob
group by ob.BookType
```

In its current state it does what I need it to and groups books by **BookType** and sums their balances, as seen below.

[image]

However I need the name of any book that belongs to that **BookType** as part of the result.

If I select the **BookName** column and then group by it like below, it results in more unique entries and to an extent undoes the original grouping.

```sql
select distinct
(select sum(ob.Balance)),
ob.BookType,
ob.BookName
from orders.OrderBooks ob
group by ob.BookType, ob.BookName
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Probably something like SELECT DISTINCT SUM(ob.Balance) OVER ( PARTITION BY ob.BookType) AS type_balance, ob.bookname FROM orders.OrderBooks ob

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added the current results, will try and mock the desired results.

Comment: @Error_2646 Ill give that a go, thank you.

Comment: If you can avoid using images for data... much easier to read on all devices as formatted text.

Comment: @Dale K Will keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT 
    Balance = SUM(Balance) OVER (PARTITION BY BookType), 
    BookType,
    BookName,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BookType ORDER BY BookName DESC)
  FROM orders.OrderBooks
)
SELECT Balance, BookType, BookName 
  FROM x 
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b271a9f39abddfd3e955e0f1ed9b1caf)

`ORDER BY BookName DESC` was dealer's choice. If you truly don't care which title shows up in the result, you can use any ordering you like. If you want the results to be random every time, you can use `ORDER BY NEWID()`.

In general I like this flexibility better than the `TOP (1)` subquery approach, in addition to a single scan instead of an additional table access per row. But you can also do it a different way; just take min/max of the bookname, too:

```
SELECT Balance = SUM(Balance), 
       BookType,
       BookName = MIN(BookName) -- or MAX()
FROM dbo.OrderBooks
GROUP BY BookType;
```

You can see these give similar results [in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d5d41b8f611c9264d7296c6d86f677ad). Plan is simpler, too; most notably: no spools. However when you use an aggregate function against that column, it makes it harder to provide arbitrary/random results, and if you intend to add other columns pulled from the right row, you'll need to go back to the row_number solution.

Comment: What a beautifully simple answer, thank you so much. 

My actual problem set is a bit more complex than the example given but your solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your time and educated, well explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery to get a single book name of that type. This assumes there's an `ID` field and you want to pull the most recent one:

```
select 
    Balance = (select sum(ob.Balance)),
    ob.BookType,
    BookName = (SELECT TOP(1) ob.BookName FROM orders.OrderBooks ob2 WHERE ob2.BookType = ob.BookType ORDER BY ob2.ID DESC)
from orders.OrderBooks ob
group by ob.BookType, ob.BookName
```

Comment: I believe this actually [doesn't give the right results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=211d4a1add71af78827fff7eb06939ad).